# expected number of dependent trials until n successes

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value, markov-process, bernoulli-distribution

In case of bernoulli experiments, I know that the expected value for the number of trials needed to have $n$ successes is n/p. (where p is probability of success for each trial). Now my question is, if this does still hold, if the success in one trial depends on the success of the previous one. My intuition would be that it's still true, but I don't know how to prove that.

An example would be the probability of a rainy day. Let's say the probability of a rainy day is $p_1=\frac{2}{7}$. If we already know that the day before has been rainy, the (now conditional) probability of another rainy day is $p_2=\frac{4}{7}$. Nevertheless, I would still think that the expected number of successive days I have to wait, to witness exactly 2 rainy days is (without further knowledge) k=$\frac{2}{2/7}=7$. But all the proofs I know depend on the independency between successive events. Is there a proof for the dependent case? Or is my assumption even wrong?

Comment: $``$If we already know that the day before has been rainy, the (now conditional) probability of another rainy day is $p_2=4/7."$ Is that by definition, so that you're dealing with a Markov process? Or is that your own idea? For (independent) Bernoulli trials, rain today is independent of rain yesterday. In a Markov process they need not be independent.

Comment: yes, It is a markov process. I meant that by definition.